# Support for modern CSS features on Falkon browser?

Tags: css, angular, browser, chromium, polyfills

Is there any way to support modern CSS features like `calc()`, `clamp()`, `min()/max()` etc on Falkon 3.2.0?

Those don't work on Falkon since it's based on Chromium 69, which was released back in 2018.

Or instead, is there a way to simulate the effect of the aformentioned functions?

I read about CSS Polyfills but I'm quite confused on where to start/what to do.

The project I'm working on is in Angular 13.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use package `css-vars-ponyfill`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill

`npm i css-vars-ponyfill`

```
cssVars({
  include: 'style',
  onlyLegacy: false,
  watch: true,
  onComplete(cssText, styleNode, cssVariables) {
    console.log(cssText);
  }
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-vars-ponyfill-29-aa9xuj?file=src%2Fmain.ts